# Which in-memory key-value store I should choose for storing big data objects?

Tags: mongodb, redis, memcached, in-memory-database, key-value-store

I want to write an application that stores and retrieves big data objects (in several gigabytes).

As the objects are read and written sequentially, I wish every data object is stored in the following way.
Only the first several tens of megabytes is stored in memory, and the other part is stored on disk.

Is there any existing in-memory key-value store that can satisfy my requirements? Like memcached, redis, mongodb?